# how to convert this javascript to jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, but I'm not sure how to convert it to jquery because of the `check` variable which I am using to see if the stuff inside the `if` statement happened at least once. `gph_img_list` is the name tag for lots of radio buttons.

```
    var check = false;
    for (var i=0; i < gph_img_list.length; i++) { 
        if (gph_img_list[i].value == var_gph_img.innerHTML) { 
            gph_img_list[i].checked = true;
            check = true;               
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!check) {
        var_gph_img.innerHTML = "";
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean 'convert it to jQuery'? How/why would you convert a bool variable to jQuery?

Comment: What does `var_gph_img` pertain to?

Comment: @Lance, its a span tag i am using to store a string value

Comment: @glosrob, i mean to convert this whole code. I was hoping to use some jquery looping code to go though all the radio tags with that name attribute equal to gph_img_list. And still detect if the if condition occurred even once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** function...

```
​var check = $(gph_img_list).filter(function (index, element) {
    return element.value === var_gph_img.innerHTML;
}).first().attr("checked", true).length > 0;

if (!check) { var_gph_img.innerHTML = ""; }
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36qcC/1/)** where there is no checkbox checked because the text **doesn't** match. (Change the 'a' in the div to x, y or z to see the difference)

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36qcC/2/)** where there is a checkbox checked because the text **does** match.

Comment: The OP's code only sets the first matching item to be checked.  Your code sets all matching items to be checked.

Comment: You need to look carefully at what the OP's code does.  Your code does not accomplish the same thing.  Your code now doesn't check any items and clears the HTML on the wrong items.

Comment: It's still setting more than one item to checked.  The OP's code only sets the first matching item to checked.

Comment: this didn't make the radio button checked

Comment: @omega Added two fiddles to my answer to demonstrate that the checkboxes do get checked. Can you create a fiddle that shows your scenario?

Comment: @omega Did you try the two fiddles in my example? Can you tell me what's different in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you gain by converting this to jQuery, but based on what you've shown, this should accomplish the same task using jQuery wherever practical:

```
var text = $(var_gph_img).html();
var check = false;
$(gph_img_list).each(function() {
    if (this.value == text) {
        check = true;
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
        return(false);  // stop the .each() loop
    }
});
if (!check) {
    $(var_gph_img).html("");
}
```

If you want to do this even more efficiently, you'd have to show us your HTML so we could devise jQuery selectors to do most of the work.

Comment: @BartRiemens: OP specifically asked for jQuery, so I'd imagine that's why it was used "wherever practical" as mentioned in the answer. I feel like your edit takes away from that (even though your edits make things more efficient). Although I guess if jfriend00 doesn't mind, my objection is moot.

Comment: @BartRiemens - I rolled back your edits.  I don't think you should just wholesale change my code.  Editing is generally for fixing mistakes or adding clarification, not for imposing your opinion on how the code should be written.  You are free to write your own answer or to offer comments on improving my code and I will decide whether to change my answer based on your feedback.  It's also kind of sneaky to make that many changes and not even leave a comment as to what you did and why.  If Colin had not commented, I might not have seen the edits.  Thanks for the head's-up Colin.

Comment: Np. Surprisingly, that edit received 2 approval votes.

Comment: @Colin Why is that surprising? Isn't the idea to have the best possible answers on Stack Overflow provided by the community? I don't see the problem here and why am I not allowed to suggest some improvements (together with a change message.) A lot of dev's will just copy a snippet like this, so let's make sure it is the best code out there. Anyway! Thanks and cheers!

Comment: @BartRiemens: My objection to the edit was twofold, and alluded to above. 1.) Reverting some of the jQuery-specific code to its vanilla JS equivalent is, imo, not in line with what the question asked (regardless of any benefits gained by doing so). The question specifically asked for help converting vanilla JS to its jQuery equivalent. 2.) This is mentioned above, namely that edits are generally for clarification or errors, and not for rewriting code based on your personal opinion. Anyway, the above is just my opinion and I certainly appreciate your sentiment toward bettering the community! :)

Comment: @BartRiemens - Bart, you changed almost every line of the code.  If you want to propose an answer that different, then propose a different answer.  That's not a proposed improvement - that's a rewrite, a different answer.  I've done new answers before that started out: "This is the same concept as proposed by xxxx, but improved in this way".  I do that in the spirit of getting the best answers out there.  I also sometime write a comment with my improvement suggestion and see if the author wants to upgrade to it.